# "More than one row with the given identifier was found". The problem: it's not an identifier

Tags: java, hibernate, h2, spring-test

***Note.** It's a heavily trimmed down version of the problematic code. I spent a lot of time making it. I believe it's pretty MREish. I do hope for a helpful answer*

Here's my test

```java
package by.afinny.credit.unit.repository;

import by.afinny.credit.entity.Card;
import by.afinny.credit.enumeration.CardStatus;
import by.afinny.credit.repository.CardRepository;
import org.assertj.core.api.SoftAssertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.EnumSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.Sql;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

@DataJpaTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Sql(
        executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD,
        scripts = {"/schema-h2.sql", "/data-h2.sql"}
)
class CardRepositoryTest {
    @Autowired
    private CardRepository cardRepository;
    private final static UUID ACCOUNT_ID = UUID.fromString("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000ac1");


    @ParameterizedTest
    @EnumSource(CardStatus.class)
    void testFindByAccountIdAndCardStatusNot(CardStatus excludedCardStatus) {
        List<Card> cards = cardRepository.findByAccountIdAndCardStatusNot(ACCOUNT_ID, excludedCardStatus); // never gets beyond this line, though
        cards.forEach(card -> verifyProperties(card, excludedCardStatus));
    }

    private void verifyProperties(Card card, CardStatus excludedCardStatus) {
        SoftAssertions.assertSoftly(softAssertions -> {
            softAssertions.assertThat(card.getAccount().getId()).isEqualTo(ACCOUNT_ID);
            softAssertions.assertThat(card.getCardStatus()).isNotEqualTo(excludedCardStatus);
        });
    }
}
```

Here are my scripts:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PUBLIC.account
(
    id                        UUID           PRIMARY KEY
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PUBLIC.card
(
    id                UUID             PRIMARY KEY,
    account_id        UUID             NOT NULL REFERENCES account (id),
    status            VARCHAR(30)      NOT NULL
);
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PUBLIC.account
(
    id                        UUID           PRIMARY KEY
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PUBLIC.card
(
    id                UUID             PRIMARY KEY,
    account_id        UUID             NOT NULL REFERENCES account (id),
    status            VARCHAR(30)      NOT NULL
);
```

My entities:

```java
package by.afinny.credit.entity;

import by.afinny.credit.enumeration.CardStatus;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
@Table(name = "card")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Card {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private UUID id;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "status", nullable = false, length = 30)
    private CardStatus cardStatus;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Account account;
}
```

```java
package by.afinny.credit.entity;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
@Table(name = "account")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Account {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private UUID id;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "account")
    private Card card;
}
```

```java
package by.afinny.credit.enumeration;

public enum CardStatus {
    BLOCKED,
    ACTIVE,
    CLOSED,
    NON_ACTIVE
}
```

```java
package by.afinny.credit.repository;

import by.afinny.credit.entity.Card;
import by.afinny.credit.enumeration.CardStatus;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

@Repository
public interface CardRepository extends JpaRepository<Card, UUID> {
    List<Card> findByAccountIdAndCardStatusNot(UUID accountId, CardStatus excludedStatus);
}
```

Properties:

```java
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MODE=MySQL;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    username: sa
    password:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
    show-sql: true
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    properties:
      hibernate:
        format_sql: true
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: false
      settings:
        web-allow-others: true
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: test

logging:
  level:
    org:
      hibernate:
        type: TRACE
      springframework:
          jdbc:
            core: TRACE
            datasource:
              init: DEBUG
          test:
            context:
              jdbc: DEBUG
```

I can include the pom as well if it's necessary, but I don't think so (basically all it has is `starter-data-jpa`, `starter-test`, `lombok`, `h2`)

The problem:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: More than one row with the given identifier was found: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000ac1, for class: by.afinny.credit.entity.Card
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.loadByUniqueKey(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2486)
```

Why does it see the foreign key to the `account` table as an identifier? I can't wrap my head around it. It should be valid for a table to refer to the same primary key of another table

Interestingly, it runs fine with `ACTIVE`, but fails in all other cases

What's the root of this problem? How do I fix it?

Comment: Please show the definition of your JPA/Hibernate entity, and provide a [mre] of the code that triggers the actual error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because there are two candidates for the `card` field in `Account` entity.

> It should be valid for a table to refer to the same primary key of another table

It is valid if you use `@ManyToOne` association type. For `@OneToOne` it's invalid.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean? There's no card field in `Account`. `Card` references `Account` but not vice versa

Comment: I mean this field:

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "account")
    private Card card;

Comment: But isn't the exception thrown at the time of script execution that doesn't take `javax.persistence` annotations into account at all?

Comment: If you create a table by your own script - only you are making rules. If you let Hibernate ddl generator (or tools like JPA Buddy) create the script - yes, it will take the annotations into account and will make account_id unique.

Comment: Please see the edit. I hope it makes things clearer

Comment: Oh boy, I just realized what you said and that you were right